# JfreeChart Axis custom precision or range

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to plot a XYPlot using JfreeChart. My X axis has number or client say 30, 50 ,70 
and Y axis has cache hit ratio( Value of which sometime varies by 0.01) When i set AutoRange the y axis show range as 0.1 0.2 0.3..... 1.0. So sometimes my plot is nearly straight line  since it varies by such a small factor.

I have tried this code

```
             JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
             "Effect of Number of Clients", // Title
             "Number of Clients", // x-axis Label
             "Cache Hit Ratio", // y-axis Label
             datasetLRU, // Dataset
             PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // Plot Orientation
             true, // Show Legend
             true, // Use tooltips
             false // Configure chart to generate URLs?
             );
             chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
             plot= chart.getXYPlot();
             plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.black);
             plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
             plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

             final ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
             axis.setAutoRange(false);

             final NumberAxis axis2 = new NumberAxis("Axis 2");
             axis2.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
             axis2.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.01));

             plot.setDataset(1, datasetMARS);
             plot.setRenderer(1, new StandardXYItemRenderer());
             plot.setDataset(2, datasetNEW);
             plot.setRenderer(2, new StandardXYItemRenderer());
```

So Can any one help in setting Y axis range as 0.01 0.02 0.03 .... 0.98 0.99 1.00 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't configure the range axis because you create axis2 but you never assign it. When using auto range you can also configure the minium size of an auto ranged axis (method setAutoRangeMinimumSize(double)).

Please try the following source code part:

```
final NumberAxis axis2 = plot.getRangeAxis();
axis2.setAutoRange(true);
axis2.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
axis2.setAutoRangeMinimumSize(0.001);
axis2.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.01));
```

Comment: Does that answer your question? In such a case please mark your question as resolved. Thanks!